# Embed batch files in MS Word

Tags: batch-file, ms-word, embed

I have a MS-DOS batch file `.bat`. I want to embed this in a MS Word document where the contents can be viewed at later point in time.

If I copy the `.bat` file from the MS Word, paste it outside the document and open in a good text editor, the contents are clipped and first line contains the location. This is not of much help.

Is it possible to view it within MS Word itself ? If I double click, the batch file `.bat` is executed, instead of showing.

I have embeded the `.bat` file using this step. `Insert -> Object -> Create From File -> Display As Icon -> OK`.

Please let me know if there is any other way to achieve this.

Comment: Have you tried using Macros? specifically use `RunApp` function - http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=187188

Comment: Would it be possible to copy from the document and paste outside and view ?

Comment: Do you want to be able to run the `.bat` file from within Word, or do you expect someone else always to copy the content, paste it into a text editor, save it, and run the new file?

Comment: @mojo Both actually. They must able to run it by double clicking but I want them to have an option to view its contents. If its not possible to have both, viewing is preferable.

Comment: When I do what you've described in MS Word 2010, I can double-click on the file and it will run. I cannot view the file directly, but if I right-click on it and choose `Packager Shell Object Object` / `Properties` -> `Security`, I can see the path to the file. (You may have to attempt to launch it first before the file exists.)